# The old asp.net 2.0 project can't run under Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express

Tags: asp.net

Before a asp.net 2.0 + ajax 1.0 projact can run well under Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2005 Express

Now When I try to run it under Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express, I get the following error.

I don't want to upgrade the project to Vs 2010, how can I do? Thanks!

> Could not load file or assembly System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to solve this problem is to remove and add a new web.config file and add your necessary keys and values.
Other wise create a new project in visual web developer 2010 and import all your project files to it.